# Any ideas why my blueimp jQuery file upload script is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I'm using blueimp JQuery file upload script to fancy the uploading of files. You can download it here: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/zipball/master (ZIP).

Here is a snippet of the JavaScript code:

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';

    // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
    // Dirs
    url: 'accesspoint/upload.php',
    uploadDir: 'accesspoint/files/',
    thumbnailsDir: '',

    // Options
    autoUpload: 1,
    maxNumberOfFiles: 1,
    limitConcurrentUploads: 1,
    maxFileSize: 1000000,
    });

    // Load existing files:
    $.getJSON($('#fileupload form').prop('action'), function (files) {
        var fu = $('#fileupload').data('fileupload');
        fu._adjustMaxNumberOfFiles(-files.length);
        fu._renderDownload(files)
            .appendTo($('#fileupload .files'))
            .fadeIn(function () {
                // Fix for IE7 and lower:
                $(this).show();
            });
    });

    // Open download dialogs via iframes,
    // to prevent aborting current uploads:
    $('#fileupload .files a:not([target^=_blank])').live('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('<iframe style="display:none;"></iframe>')
            .prop('src', this.href)
            .appendTo('body');
    });
});
```

Now take a look at http://www.mcemperor.nl/test/appstest/blueimpjqueryfileupload/example/. We can upload a file, and it works.
Now if I upload a file which is larger than the maximum file size defined in the JavaScript snippet above, then you'll see something like this.
[image: File upload like it's supposed to.]

Perfect, works as expected. (Note that I have set the maximum upload size to 1000000 bytes, so if you upload [a file of 1 MB](http://www.mcemperor.nl/test/appstest/blueimpjqueryfileupload/example/real_1mb.bin), it states the file is too big.)

But... Now when I paste the same script (with some small modifications) as a module into a framework of some kind, the script won't work properly; I get this:
[image: File upload that is not the idea...]

As you can see, The 'delete entry' icon is smaller (it's supposed to be square) and nothing happens when I click on it.

I do not have any clue what **can be** the problem. Does anyone have **ideas**?

- Can using this script inside another `<form>` be the problem?
- Can multiple elements with the same id be the problem?
- Can collisions between javascripts (e.g. redefining functions or objects) be the problem?

Comment: It looks like pasting _"the same script (with some small modifications) as a module into a framework of some kind"_ has broken the CSS includes.  Check the URL to the CSS file for the plugin.

Comment: @Sparky: Not only the CSS rules, also the onclick event...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how to fix the scripts, but maybe a workaround would be to locate the element using FireBug and patch it with a css entry or a jquery function.  Also, you might take a look at jquery.fileupload-ui.css which is the css file responsible for overriding jqueryUI elements for the control.  I do know that the buttons are styleable independently.  Again, I am not for certain, but there may be a class added via script to change the icon on the delete button.